# "operation not permitted" when copying from guest to host shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am using virtualBox with Ubuntu 10.04 guest, and use share folder to share files between host and guest.
On trying to copy files from guest to host.

I get "operation not permitted" on some files.

It seems that these are some unique file type, with file size = 0).

Is there any idea how to resolve it ?

EDIT:
I am using ubuntu 10.04 in Guest OS, and windows 7, as Host OS.
The 0 bytes, seems like pipe here is example for such file:
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/sf_shared_prj/hh/hh_sdk/src/linux/linux-04.02.00.07/include/config/usb/sisusbvga/con.h': Operation not permitted

Comment: What 0-byte files are these that you've shared? Also, what's the host OS?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 10.04 in Guest OS, and windows 7, as Host OS.
The 0 bytes, seems like pipe here is example for such file:
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/sf_shared_prj/hh/hh_sdk/src/linux/linux-04.02.00.07/include/config/usb/sisusbvga/con.h': Operation not permitted